# Php Quickbooks desktop: login failed

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have used php dev kit from https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
It was working okay before and i have changed nothing in code or in db, but now quickbooks giving login failed error. Here is my qwc file. Connections are okay, urls are valid. Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
<AppName>QuickBooks Syncer</AppName>
<AppID></AppID>
<AppURL>https://example.com/quickbooks/qbwc</AppURL>
<AppDescription>QuickBooks syncer description</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>https://example.com/quickbooks/support</AppSupport>
<UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
<OwnerID>{ca2c1113-d780-0a04-dd42-eac924cefa0e}</OwnerID>
<FileID>{1b512285-2ba8-9e64-3979-f48483ce46d6}</FileID>
<QBType>QBFS</QBType>
<Notify>false</Notify>
<Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>10</RunEveryNMinutes>
</Scheduler>
<IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

Quickbooks response: Login failed: quickbooks

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong password.

The password is stored in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table.

Check (and, if neccessary) change the password in that table. It can be stored in plain-text or MD5 or SHA1 hashed.

Comment: On first connect, everything works. But when start processing invoices it shows login failed.

Comment: side question, does qb desktop flag or save unauthorized web connector servers?

Comment: Post your logs. The Web Connector does absolutely nothing special or fancy here. It tries to connect. If auth succeeds, it continues. If not, it stops. There's no special flagging or saving of anything.

Comment: I have 50 invoices to process in qb; if there is an error on invoice 10, qb stops processing next invoices. I want to process 50 invoices, and if there is an error, it should proceed to next one.

Comment: Plus, what does these limits mean: $driver_options = array('max_log_history' => 32000, 'max_queue_history' => 1024); BTW, i am using your Codigniter example code

Comment: Please spend some time actually looking at the examples: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php#L222  and reading the docs: http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte  http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector#error_handlers_for_traditional_integrations